# SunOS - (Bash) Grep Command To Get after lines from match that doesn't contain pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

i've a issue that i mentioned at the title.

There are lines in my file like:

```
<Hi>
<Test>
<Test2>
</Test2>
</Test>
</Hi>
```

So i need to get **"Hi"** tag's whole content. But i don't have a gnu grep and can't install it i'm not root on the machine. I can use only :

```
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
```

**So can't use -A and -B commands or other gnu grep commands, can you please show me a way out..**

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This has been discussed already. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: actually this's not the same..And also this post that you sent is very old 4 years changes everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the venerable `sed`?

```
sed -n '/<Hi>/,/<\/Hi>/p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your system have `awk`, if so, try:

```
awk '/<Hi>/,/<\/Hi>/' file
<Hi>
<Test>
<Test2>
</Test2>
</Test>
</Hi>
```

Or you could use:

```
awk '/<Hi>/{f=1} /<\/Hi>/ {f=0;print} f' file
```

Comment: It gave me that:
awk: record `00:00:00,022 DEBUG c...' too long
 record number 9

Comment: Test the second option I added. Both should work since you have tag `ubuntu`. What version of `ubuntu` are you on.

Comment: Sorry that gave me error :


awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: Cam you give me the output of `cat /etc/*-release`. I am testing this on `Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS`

Comment: cat: cannot open /etc/*-release ,   i don't know exact version of Linux but i just learned that i'm not on a UBuntu computer it's a SunOS "uname -mrs" command says. I Checked here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/   to learn version and got that.. Sorry for wrong information.. Its a SUNOS

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/<Hi>/,/<\/Hi>/p' file
```

Perl one-liner..

```
perl -ne 'print if /<Hi>/ .. /<\/Hi>/' file
```